# Aggregating data with respect to dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  Customer Id Start Date  End Date     Count  
  1403120020  2014-03-13  2014-03-17   38.0 
  1403120020  2014-03-18  2014-04-16  283.0
  1403120020  2014-04-17  2014-04-25  100.0 
  1403120020  2014-04-26  2014-05-15  50.0  
  1812040169  2018-12-07  2018-12-19  122.0
  1812040169  2018-12-19  2018-12-20   10.0  
  1812040169  2018-12-21  2019-01-18  365.0
```

Here for a single customer I have multiple start dates within a particular month and one of the end date for that month lies in next month. I want to have one start and one end date for a customer in the following fashion with the count being summed up:

```
  Customer Id Start Date  End Date     Count   
  1403120020  2014-03-13  2014-04-16   321
  1403120020  2014-04-17  2014-05-15  150.0  
  1812040169  2018-12-07  2019-1-18    497
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = (df.groupby('Customer_Id').agg({'Start_Date':'first', 'End_Date':'last', 'Count':'sum'})
        .reset_index())

print(df)
   Customer_Id  Start_Date    End_Date  Count
0   1403120020  2014-03-13  2014-04-16  321.0
1   1812040169  2018-12-07  2019-01-18  497.0
```

**EDIT :**

```
df['grp'] = df['Start_Date'].dt.month
df = (df.groupby(['Customer_Id','grp'])
        .agg({'Start_Date':'first', 'End_Date':'last', 'Count':'sum'})
        .reset_index().drop('grp', axis=1))

print(df)
   Customer_Id Start_Date    End_Date  Count
0   1403120020 2014-03-13  2014-04-16  321.0
1   1403120020 2014-04-17  2014-05-15  150.0
2   1812040169 2018-12-07  2019-01-18  497.0
```

Comment: I want the end date that lies in the immediate next month. This solution will not work if I have the dataset where in each month I have multiple start dates for a particular customer.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Could show us an example of your desired test case to correct the logic.

Comment: Alternative should be `.groupby('Customer_Id', as_index=False)` :)

Comment: I have updated my question, and added a few more records.